# Is it possible to emulate a polarization filter during image processing, using C++ or OpenCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv3.0, polarization

I've looked all over Stack and other sources, but I haven't seen any code that seems to successfully emulate what a polarization filter does, reducing glare. The application I want for this code won't allow for a physical filter, so I was wondering if anyone had tried this.

I'm using OpenCV image processing (mat) in C++ on an Android platform, and glare is interfering with the results I'm trying to get. Imagine a lost object you're trying to find based on a finite set of Red/Green/Blue values; if the object is smooth, glare would render bad results. And that's my current problem.

Answer (score 2):

OK, no, there's no virtual polarization that can be accomplished just with code. It's possible to find (via image color saturation) glare spots on shiny objects, and those can be overwritten with nearby pixels without glare, but that's not the same thing as real polarization. That requires a physical, metal mesh in front of the lens, or sensor, to eliminate those stray light waves that create glare.

Tell you what. The person who invents the virtual polarization filter, using just code, will be an instant billionaire since every cell phone and digital camera company will want to license the patent.